# Mysql Using If Statements to move to the next column

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to update a MySQL table. Using the UPDATE function.

My columns are:

```
time_started, time_in_1, time_in_2, time_in_3.
```

What I want is where `time_started` is not null then move to the next column but then if `time_in_1` is also not null move to the next column and so on. could anyone help on this?

Comment: [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table 
  SET time_started = IFNULL(time_started, newValue, time_started), 
       time_1 = IFNULL(time_1, newValue, time_1),
       time_2 = IFNULL(time_2, newValue, time_2);
```

This will set each column to newValue if `NULL`, otherwise keep their original value.

Comment: This is the current code I have and it doesn't work "UPDATE staff SET active = 1,
time_started = IF NULL(time_started,'$_POST[in_time]', time_started), 
       time_in_1 = IF NULL(time_in_1,'$_POST[in_time]', time_in_1),
       time_in_2 = IF NULL(time_in_2,'$_POST[in_time]', time_in_2)
WHERE staff_id = '$_POST[staff_id]'";

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What happens? Any errors/warnings?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that this seems like a really strange (and not very extensible) table structure. The SQL required isn't exactly beautiful, and I'd say extending it beyond a few columns won't make anyone happy :)

That said, this should do what you want;

```sql
SET @value := '2001-01-01';

UPDATE myTable SET
  time_in_3 =    IF(time_started IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_1    IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_2    IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_3    IS NULL, @value, time_in_3),
  time_in_2    = IF(time_started IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_1    IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_2    IS NULL, @value, time_in_2),
  time_in_1    = IF(time_started IS NOT NULL AND
                    time_in_1    IS NULL, @value, time_in_1),
  time_started = IF(time_started IS NULL, @value, time_started)
WHERE id=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle showing it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b149c/1).

Comment: How would you say I did this?

Comment: @user2044422 `@value` is where you pass in the time you want inserted. As you can see, you need to pass it in 4 times (if you pass in the value right away, you can remove the SET line). If you're using mysqli, that's trivial, if you're still using the deprecated mysql_* API, you'll need to painstakingly build the string yourself.

Comment: @user2044422 Hard to help with only "can't get it to work" as info.

Comment: the query seems to run but I get no data in my MySQL table.

Comment: @user2044422 What does your table look like? The `where id=1` part is just to update the correct row if there are many, you may be choosing row to update in some other manner.

Comment: I have used where id ='$_POST[staff_id]'